# Auto update my dateRangeInput at shinyR UI

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, shinydashboard

My *Shinyr* App is using a `dateRangeInput` selector with the default values of date range between yesterday and 15 days ago , however when the App is running for more than on day , I wish that the default date range will update accordingly , I know that at the server side you could invoke `invalidateLater` , but I have no idea what can be done at the UI side of the App , the `dateRangeInput` at the UI side looks like this :

```
dateRangeInput('dateRange',label = 'Date',start = Sys.Date() - 15, end = Sys.Date()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not sure why you want to do this on the client side, but there is a way. You can add a JavaScript on the Client that does exactly what any construction with `invalidateLater` would do. But this gets much more confusing than the server side version.

Code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput('dateRange',label = 'Date',start = Sys.Date() - 15, end = Sys.Date() - 1),
  tags$script(HTML("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var initDate = new Date();

      setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        if(currentDate.getDate() != initDate.getDate()) {
          initDate = currentDate;

          var start = new Date();
          start.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 15);

          var end = new Date();
          end.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);

          /* Insert Id of your dateRangeInput */
          var dateInput = $('#dateRange').find('input');
          dateInput.eq(0).datepicker('update', start);
          dateInput.eq(1).datepicker('update', end);
        };
      /* Insert interval in millis below. */
      }, 3600000);
    });
  "))
))

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```